# NoReverseMatch named urls Django

Tags: python, django, match, django-urls, reverse

Any ideas why this returns a `NoReverseMatch` error? From a fork of [djano-ratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) called [updown](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown).

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/rate/(?P<score>[\d\-]+)/$', AddRatingFromModel(), {
    'app_label': 'appname',
    'model': 'Thing',
    'field_name': 'rating',
}, name='thing_rating'),
```

The template:

```
<div id='vote'><a href='{% url thing_rating %}'>Up</a></div>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

---

EDIT: added view for clarity

```
def index(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                         {'thing_list':thing_list},
                         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Have you included that url conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in arguments (I use keyword args here, but positional is okay too) for the url's parameters.

In a list view, you're probably iterating over your items, so something like this works:

```
{% for thing in thing_list %}
    ...
    <div id='vote'><a href='{% url "thing_rating" object_id=thing.id score=5 %}'>Up</a></div>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I think you also need quotes around the url name.

Here's more on the url tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url

Comment: Did you pass valid values for object_id and score?

Comment: Oh right. Thanks! If I wanted to use `Thing.id` for `object.id`, any idea how to do that?  Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your view code, but you probably have passed a Thing to your context. If it's a `DetailView`, it's called `object` and you can use `object_id=object.id`.

Comment: My view is pretty standard. I added it above. If you have a moment to point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

Comment: Got a `ValueError: Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!` when trying `{% url 'thing_rating' object_id=Thing.id score=1 %}`.  Any idea what is wrong with that?   Thanks so much!

Comment: As to the ValueError, I'm not sure. The arguments don't look mixed to me, but try switching to positional args: `{% url 'thing_rating' thing.id 5 %}`.

Comment: Awesome. You have helped me understand url construction a lot more thoroughly.  Thanks @dokkaebi!!